# Python:what happened if there are two python version install in the same OS?

Tags: python

I want to work with **python 2** and **python 3** version. if I install those version same OS what would be happened?

is there any wrong things with it?

Comment: Both python will work independently.

Comment: No, there is nothing wrong with it. For example, I have python 2.7.10 and python 3.5.2 installed on Windows. They work completely separate from each other

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with having two versions of python installed, and it's actually quite common to do so. Usually, one would install them with different names (`python` vs `python3`, for example) to avoid confusion though.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python from command line then you can run python command for python 2 and python3 command for python 3.

In ide such as pycharm you can select the project intepretor from settings.